# Django If an action is added to the form, the form is not submitted

Tags: python, django

I have a form in my Django project. I want to when user fills the form and click the send button form will be posted and redirect a URL. I am using `action` in form for that but when I do this the form is **not submitted** but it opens the link, and when I delete `action`, the form is being submitted. I do not know why it is not working?

**approval_page.html**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
   class="lead_form"
   id="lead_form"
   action="{% url 'approvals:approve_pending' pk=approval.pk%}"
   >
   <!-- Very Important csrf Token -->
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form_approval.media }}
   {{ form_approval|crispy }}
   <input type="hidden" name="rank_name" value="{{ waiting.rank.rank_name }}" />
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" value="Approve" >
   <a href="{% url 'approvals:decline_pending' pk=approval.pk%}">
   <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="approve-btn">Decline</button>
   </a>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def approval_page(request, id):
...

    form_approval = LeadApprovalForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form_approval.is_valid():
            print(request.POST.get('approver_name', None))
            lead_approval = form_approval.save()
            lead_approval.user = request.user
            lead_approval.approval_id = approval
            lead_approval.rank = request.POST.get('rank_name', None)
            lead_approval.save()

        else:
            form_approval = LeadApprovalForm()
    context = {
     ...
        'form_approval ': form_approval ,
     ...
     }
    return render(request, 'approval_page.html', context)

def approve_pending(request, pk):
    pending_approval = ApprovalProcess.objects.get(pk=pk)
    customer = pending_approval.doc_id.owner
    pdf = pending_approval.doc_id
    priority_number = 0
    ...

    approval_step.delta_time = abs((approval_step.finish_time - approval_step.start_time).days)

    approval_step.save()

    ...

    return redirect('ocr_approve', pending_approval.doc_id.id)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^ocrs/(?P<id>\d+)/analysis/approve$', views.approval_page, name="ocr_approve"),
path('approvals/<int:pk>/', views.approve_pending, name='approve_pending'),
```

Comment: What exactly makes you think the form is not submitting? If the new page opens the form has been submit

Comment: When I look at the admin page, I can see that it does not submit or save the form.

Comment: If you add a print to `approve_pending` do you see it?

Comment: When I write action method, it do not run in `if form_approval.is_valid()`

Comment: No, if you change the action to `approve_pending` that is where the form will be submitted. There will *never* be a POST request to `approval_page`